# .htaccess: Redirect removing file extensions unless part of a query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Many answers here come close but none are complete.

I would like .htaccess to redirect and remove php/html extensions and trailing slashes so all files, directories, and bootstraps look the same. The problem is that a URL might, or might not, include a query string with an external URL link which therefore should not be altered.

1. Scenario 1: Remove ".php" from simple URLs.

   - This: *examle.com/file.PHP*
   - Becomes: *examle.com/file*
2. Scenario 2: Remove ".php" from URLs but not the query.

   - This: *examle.com/file.PHP?link=anothersite.com/somefile.PHP*
   - Becomes: *examle.com/file?link=anothersite.com/somefile.PHP*

I have rewrite conditions which work for one or the other scenario but can find no single solution for both.

This condition works for scenario 1 but fails in scenario 2 in that it also strips the extension from the link in the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/(.+)\.php
```

This (with a \?) works in scenario 2 but ONLY works if there is a query (a question mark) so it fails in scenario 1.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/(.+)\.php\?
```

The solution would be a regular expression which looks at the whole string unless there is a question mark. Or possibly somehow parses the string at any question mark. I've tried putting a "zero or one" qualifier at the question mark but it caused a redirect loop.

The completed code looks something close to this.

```
# Remove extensions shown in address bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\/(.+)\.(php|jar|html|shtml|htm) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Display php file if it exist 
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
rewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: So what do you want `examle.com/file.PHP?link=anothersite.com/somefile.PHP` be redirected to or you want to leave this *as is*?

Comment: In theory, examle.com/file?link=anothersite.com/somefile.PHP Removing .php from the base url but leaving it in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule to make it work for both URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. It fails on scenario 2. It removes the .php from the query string so that: examle.com/file.PHP?link=anothersite.com/somefile.PHP becomes: examle.com/file?link=anothersite.com/somefile

Comment: WOOHOO! works! It's beyond me why it works but it does. Gonna have to study this, Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: anubhava I'm very sorry but evidently Stackoverflow won't let a nube like me upvote??? even soluttions to my own question. Which seems odd. But it is much appreciated. Now I just need to figure out how to mark this answered.

Comment: No issues, you've now accepted it and can upvote if you want :)

Comment: I see why it works now. ".php" which is both after any string which does not contain a question mark  and before a space. I didn't understand the %{THE_REQUEST} format.  Armed with this new knowledge I wrote out a little htaccess to clean and direct URLs. As it seems these questions are asked frequently, I've posted the relevant bits in an answer below. If you have time to take a look and critique the result It would be great but if not, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I've included this final code for any who come here with similar issues related to clean & pretty URLs.

The code below should:

1. Remove trailing garbage (slashes, question marks, dots etc...)
2. Hide unwanted extensions and indexes
3. Display the related index.php / filename.php

Thanks to anubhava for the needed solution.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks   
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

# Remove trailing question marks.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R,L]

# Remove unwanted extensions, dots, "index", punctuation, trailing slash
#   First condition group removed from anywhere in the path.
#   Second condition group only removed from the end of the path.
#   The rule will not alter text in the query. 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+?)\.(php|jar|html|shtml|htm)([^\s]*?)[\s?] [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+?)(\/index|\/|\.|,|\!])[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%3 [R,NE,L]

# If path points to a directory containing an index.php, use it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/index.php [L]

# ElseIf path/filename points to a php file, use it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

################################################################
# Below here is only needed if you want a bootstrap
# Without this, files will display or 404 as normal.
################################################################

# If none of the above conditions are met, 
# and the request is not an actual file (.jpg, .svg, etc.),
# display the bootstrap file making the path
# a query string for the bootstrap to parse.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?strappath=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks and please let me know if there are errors or loopholes.